# Mnist dataset pattern recognition accuracy

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, pattern-recognition, mnist

I'm completely new to matlab and this is my first project. Mnist has 60000 picture between 0 and 9 for training and 1000 picture to test. what I did is try to make a pattern for all of this 10 class (0 to 9) by using mean.then for for recognition I use Euclidean distance. this is very simple but the accuracy is really low.
I don't know where is exactly my problem to give my back this percentage of accuracy. the accuracy :1.73%

here is my code
finding 10 pattern for all of our class:

```
root = 'F:\matlab\ex1\exercise-EquivaliencOfL2DistanceAndDotProduct\dataset';

fn = strcat (root, '\MnistTrainX.mat');
load (fn);

fn = strcat (root, '\MnistTrainY.mat');
load (fn);

weights = zeros (10, 784);
b = zeros (10, 1);

im=reshape(MnistTrainX(5,:),[28 ,28]);
imshow(im,[]);
imshow(im',[]);

for c=1 : 10
    idx=find(MnistTrainY == c-1);
   weights (c,:)=mean( MnistTrainX(idx,:));
end

trainAccuray = ComputeInnerProductAccuracy(weights,b, MnistTrainX,MnistTrainY);
display(trainAccuray);

fn = strcat (root, '\MnistTestX.mat');
load (fn);

fn = strcat (root, '\MnistTestY.mat');
load (fn);


testAccuray  = ComputeInnerProductAccuracy(weights, b, MnistTestX, MnistTestY);
display(testAccuray);
```

and this is accuracy function

```
function [acc]=ComputeInnerProductAccuracy(weights, b, X, Y)

n = size(X, 1);
minmat = zeros (60000, 2);
endmat = zeros (60000, 10);
m = size(X);
a=0;
for i=1 : n
    for j=1 : 10
        endmat(i,j)=sum((X(i,:)-(weights(j,:))).^2,2);
    end

    [minmat(i,1) ,minmat(i,2)]= min(endmat(i,:));
    if minmat(i,2)== Y(i)
        a=a+1;
    end

end
acc=(a*100)/60000;
end
```

Comment: Calculating the mean of each digit as the representative digit to use and finding inner product between a query digit and each of these representative digits for classification is a very bad idea.  If you look at each of the individual digits (i.e. all 1s, 2s, etc.), they all look very different from each other.  Finding the mean of all of these digits is not a good representation of what each digit would look like in practice. BTW, your code isn't calculating the inner product.  It's calculating the Euclidean distance.

Comment: @rayryeng yes your completely right and I know it, but this our exercise and our teacher with this way gaining 82% of accuracy.
I think maybe this low of accuracy may come from my function.

Comment: ِِDear @rayryeng mind me ask you to help me with another problem ?

Comment: Sure. How can I help?

Comment: @rayryeng thank you for replaying me. I solved it near 30 min ago :D, I don't think if I can make it work by myself but it works perfectly although after 8 hours, I used kmean for increasing my accuracy. I hope this mention not disturbing you.

Comment: You didn't disturb. No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, though it's quite inefficient. I won't spend the time to make it more efficient as there are many areas that need addressing. Instead I'll focus on what is wrong. There are two things wrong with the code. Firstly is when you find which digit has the lowest distance:

```
[minmat(i,1) ,minmat(i,2)]= min(endmat(i,:));
```

Note that the second output of `min` produces the location of where the minimum is **starting at index 1**.  The class values in `Y` should contain 0 to 9 but the output index of `min` in your case is from 1 to 10.  The output minimum indices and the corresponding class values are 1 off from each other, which is probably the reason why you have such bad accuracy.

Therefore, you have to subtract 1 from `minmat(i, 2)` before you check to see if the minimum label is indeed the ground truth... or you can simply add 1 to `Y(i)` when checking:

```
[minmat(i,1) ,minmat(i,2)]= min(endmat(i,:));
if minmat(i,2)== Y(i)+1 % Change
    a=a+1;
end
```

The second thing that is incorrect is that the "inner product" function (actually you're computing the Euclidean distance.... but let's put that aside for this answer) assumes that there are always 60000 inputs yet your test set doesn't have this many inputs. This will work fine on your training data but it will report the wrong accuracy for your test data. Make sure you change all instances of 60000 in the function to `n`. This variable you've already created in your code and determines how many inputs there are.

Comment: yes. your right I become so confused with matrix dimension because they are large so I didn't attention to index part. silly mistake.thank you.

Comment: Heh heh. No problem. I am curious though. What is the accuracy now that you've corrected the comparison?

Comment: my test accuracy still low ; I mean train accuracy is 85% and test 13.5% can I do something to improve it?

Comment: Yes. Your inner product function assumes the input has 60000 samples yet your test set only has 1000. Therefore, the reported accuracy is incorrect as you're using the wrong number of total inputs. This is the problem with hard coding variables in functions as it doesn't allow for dynamic behaviour. Change the function so that it accommodates for the total number of inputs, not 60000. You've already have a `n` variable that capture this. Simply change 60000 to `n` in all areas of your code that use 60000.

Comment: wow!!!!! your right I really don't know these little thing can improve accuracy. you teach me useful things today.thank u

Comment: Ahaha no problem. The test set accuracy should be roughly 82% now from my calculations. If you want to push this further, take a look at neural networks or SVMs... In particular, convolutional neural networks. The accuracy of using CNNs is known to be at least performing at the level of classification done by humans... And sometimes better.

Comment: yes actually this exercise is for my neural network class and now I have to write this exercise with another way like argmax(wi x + bi).the accuracy for test is now 80.2% .thanks for your guide about svm and CNNs

Comment: Sounds good! Neural networks are fun. I hope you enjoy them. Good luck and you're welcome!